# responsive menu not where it should be

Tags: css

i have just made my menu a responsive menu but now it has lost the position i had it to in how do i set it back to where it should be i dont want to have to restyle all my other css codes just get tbis to sit where it should be i am sorry about my writing it not my stong point

```
/*Strip the ul of padding and list styling*/
ul {
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
position: absolute;
}

/*Create a horizontal list with spacing*/
li {
display:inline-block;
float: left;
}

/*Style for menu links*/
li a {
display:block;
width:100%;
height: 50px;
text-align: center;
line-height: 50px;
color: #fff;
background: #000000;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 18pt;
font-weight: bold;
padding-right: 15px;
}

/*Hover state for top level links*/
li:hover a {
background: #00FFFF;
}

/*Style for dropdown links*/
li:hover ul a {
background: #000000;
color: #FFFFFF;
height: 40px;
line-height: 40px;
}

/*Hover state for dropdown links*/
li:hover ul a:hover {
background: #00FFFF;
color: #fff;
}

/*Hide dropdown links until they are needed*/
li ul {
display: none;
}

/*Make dropdown links vertical*/
li ul li {
display: block;
float: none;
}

/*Prevent text wrapping*/
li ul li a {
width: auto;
min-width: 100px;
padding: 0 20px;
}

/*Display the dropdown on hover*/
ul li a:hover + .hidden, .hidden:hover {
display: block;
}

/*Style 'show menu' label button and hide it by default*/
.show-menu {
font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
text-decoration: none;
color: #fff;
background: #000000;
text-align: center;
padding: 10px 0;
display: none;
}

/*Hide checkbox*/
input[type=checkbox]{
display: none;
}

/*Show menu when invisible checkbox is checked*/
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #menu{
display: block;
}


/*Responsive Styles*/

@media screen and (max-width : 760px){
/*Make dropdown links appear inline*/
ul {
    position: static;
    display: none;
}
/*Create vertical spacing*/

/*Make all menu links full width*/
ul li, li a {
    width: 100%;
}
/*Display 'show menu' link*/
.show-menu {
    display:block;
}
}
```

a link to my website to see what wrong with it as i dont no how to add images to this www.slchandy.co.uk/prototype/booking.php

Comment: So where should your menu be?

Comment: it should sit below my company name and opening times and and above my grey text box and sidebar but since i made it responsive it floating above my div text bow and side bar if you had a look at my website take away everything after the co.uk and you will see where it should be sitting

Comment: Making something responsive doesn't make it float above something. Have you used anything like `position: absolute;`?

Comment: yes i have i have also tryed fixed static relative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have 2 options here;

Option 1:

On your booking page you are using a different style sheet? And the menu id is named differently.

Change the div name back to what it should be and include your css file.

Option: 2

Change the css for the ul like so;

```
ul {
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: static;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Hover menu;

```
ul li ul {
    float: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: auto;
   }
```

Comment: option 2 has worked perfectly only problem now is that the drop down part does not float over my text area it sift everything down

Comment: OK good. Updated code, that should work.(it does in firbug) please mark the answer as accepted :). thanks

Comment: thank you @jay you been a great help i never used firebug before i use chrome

Comment: Definateley use Firefox with firebug add on. I find it much easier, people may disagree but personal preference. Thanks for marking the answer as accepted. Good luck with the site.

Comment: i use to use firefox until they brought out they new version of it to see any site or new page i use to have to min the browser and max it again to see the site lol and thank you again

Comment: Ive never had any problems myself but whatever works. No problem your welcome mate.

Comment: it works on a my page now apart from my /prototype/index.php they turn in to something that is not a link

Comment: /prototype/index.php that url is only using float none, its not using position absolute and width auto?

Comment: i found the problem with the index.php it because i use a image under the menu with linear-gradient css once i removed that it work prefect